# cannot send socket messages outside Consumer in Django views or somewhere

Tags: python-3.x, django, sockets, django-rest-framework, django-channels

from the title shown I am not able to send socket messages here is my code

```
class ChatConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    _user = None

    @property
    def cu_user(self):
        try:
            self.user = self.scope['user']
            self._user = User.objects.get(id=self.user.id)
        except User.DoesNotExist as e:
            print(e)
        return self._user

    def connect(self):

        # Join users group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            'users',
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave app
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            'users',
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.close()

    # Receive json message from WebSocket
    def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        if content.get('command') == 'chat_handshake':
            self._handshake(content)
        elif content.get('command') == 'user_handshake':
            self.user_handshake()

    def _handshake(self, data):
        """
        Called by receive_json when someone sent a join command.
        """
        logger.info("ChatConsumer: join_chat: %s" % str(data.get('chat_id')))
        try:
            chat = "%s_%s" % (data.get('chat_type'), data.get('chat_id'))
        except ClientError as e:
            return self.handle_client_error(e)

        # Add them to the group so they get room messages
        self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat,
            self.channel_name,
        )

        # Instruct their client to finish opening the room
        self.send_json({
            'command': 'chat_handshake',
            'chat_id': str(data.get('chat_id')),
            'user': str(self.cu_user),
        })

        # Notify the group that someone joined
        self.channel_layer.group_send(
            chat,
            {
                "command": "chat_handshake",
                "user": self.cu_user,
            }
        )

    def user_handshake(self):
        key = f'user_{self.cu_user.id}'
        self.channel_layer.group_add(
            key,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.send_json({
            'command': 'user_handshake',
            'user': str(self.cu_user)
        })
        self.channel_layer.group_send(
            key,
            {
                'command': 'user_handshake',
                'user': str(self.cu_user)
            }
        )
    
    # this is not working
    def send_socket(self, event):
        logger.info(event)
        print(event)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event['message']))
```

I have written my code outside consumer like that

```
def send_to_socket(broadcast, keys=None):
    if keys:
        if not isinstance(keys, (list, tuple)):
            keys = [keys]
        sent_keys = [] # include group names
        for key in keys:
            if not key in sent_keys:
                sent_keys.append(key)
                channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
                async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                    key,
                    {
                        'type': 'send.socket',
                        'message': broadcast
                    }
                )
```

I am trying to send messages from views.py by the following code

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], url_name='socket_message')
def socket_message(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    key = ['user_1']
    broadcast = {
        'type': 'test_socket_message',
        'message': 'i am here',
        'user_id': 1
    }
    send_to_socket(broadcast, key)

    return Response({"status": "OK"})
```

I hope everything is clear from the code. I have tried many times but could not send a message.
Any help would be appreciated as I am new to channels

Answer (score 0):

As I am using **JsonWebsocketConsumer**. I made a silly mistake but it's been a great experience for me. But anyway I want to post how I was able to solve it since others may use it

**first of all** I should have written my `user_hanshake` like this

```
def user_handshake(self):
    key = f'user_{self.cu_user.id}'
    # this was changed
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
        key,
        self.channel_name
    )
    self.send_json({
        'command': 'user_handshake',
        'user': str(self.cu_user)
    })
```

in the posted code it was written as `self.channel_layer.group_add` without `async_to_sync` it was the reason that the user was not added to the groups that's why my message was not received. After that everything is working smoothly. Thank you